# Get min/max of datetime.date from pandas dataframe ignoring the NaT

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code -

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
data_dict = {"DATE_1" : [datetime.strptime("01/01/8888", "%m/%d/%Y").date()]*5,
             "DATE_2" : [datetime.strptime("01/01/1000", "%m/%d/%Y").date()]*5}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df2["NO_DATE"] = pd.NaT
df2
```

When I run the following I get a series with 5 rows - 01/01/1000 as output

```
df2[["DATE_1", "DATE_2"]].min(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

But when I run this I get all NaN as output because of NO_DATE column

```
df2[["DATE_1", "DATE_2", "NO_DATE"]].min(axis=1, skipna=True)
```

Is there a good way to get the min of dates while ignoring pd.NaT? If any row has pd.NaT ignore that column and get the min non null value.

Please note that the dates being used are out of range for datetime64[ns]

Comment: The issue is _probably_ do do some unwanted coersion under the hood. Your dates **cannot** be supported by a `datetime64[ns]` value since they are outside of the range. So despite the datetimes, if pandas wants `datetime64[ns]`, which is the supported type for datetime then those all must be coerced to `pd.NaT`. So in fact you probably have a DataFrame of all `pd.NaT` when it attempts to calculate the `min` when one column is `datetime64[ns]` and the other are objects with `datetime`

Comment: @ALollz df2["NO_DATE"] = pd.NaT, you can assign None or np.NaN here that doesn't matter. The only thing I'm trying to figure out is how to get min with NO_DATE column in picture. Yes, I cannot use datetime64[ns] because of its limited range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue in this case is an under the hood coercion because `pd.NaT` makes pandas want to force a float comparison, yet your datetime values are all out of bounds for `datetime64[ns]` so they can only be represented by `pd.NaT`.

One solution is to `stack`, such that missing values are dropped leaving you with just the `datetime` objects. Then you can `groupby` + `min` over the original index to get the min/max by row. Assigning back will align on the original row Index. If a row is entirely missing the value becomes `NaN`

```
# Make an entire row NaT for illustration
df2.iloc[1, :] = pd.NaT

df2['min'] = df2.stack().dropna().groupby(level=0).min()


print(df2)
#       DATE_1      DATE_2 NO_DATE         min
#0  8888-01-01  1000-01-01     NaT  1000-01-01
#1         NaT         NaT     NaT         NaN
#2  8888-01-01  1000-01-01     NaT  1000-01-01
#3  8888-01-01  1000-01-01     NaT  1000-01-01
#4  8888-01-01  1000-01-01     NaT  1000-01-01
```

Comment: Yes, mixed datatypes was tricky here but this worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: You don't get NaN for all NaT in most of the pandas version. Adding this helps - `.stack().dropna().min(level=0).reindex(range(len(df2)), fill_value = np.NaN)`

Comment: You do get `NaN` for most of the recent versions. Also what you propose doesn't really help. `stack` drops nulls by defult so there's no need ot `.dropna`. Then the `reindex` assumes the orignal DataFrame had a RangeIndex, but isn't needed anyway because the `groupby` is over the original index (which shouldn't be duplicated) and then Index alignment takes care of filling missing values and getting the rows properly set.